# iframe in android browser does not respect css height?

Tags: android, css, iframe

I have an iframe on a page in the android browser.  I iframe code is liek this:

```
<iframe src="somepage.html" style="height: 100px"></iframe>
```

No matter what I set the height to, the iframe always expands it's height to cover all the contents of somepage.html.   This does not happen on other browser on my computer, iphone or blackberry devices.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: maybe same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748226/android-webview-iframe-overflow

Comment: …and if you use <object data="somepage.html" style="height: 100px;"></object> instead?

Comment: My search doesn't produce a lot on this problem. But I'm experiencing it now. I can't have a list of 100 links, let's say, without a scrollable iframe on an Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<iframe width="320" height="194" src="http://example.com"></iframe>`. The link opens well with the defined height and scrolls to the bottom of the page. There might be something in the html page your are linking which is causing the iframe height to expand. Check your code or post here.