# Android WebView iframe(whit a local file) opens a new window

Tags: android, iframe

When the Android WebView loads an iframe with a local file, it opens a new window.

// it opens a new window

```
<iframe src="file:///sdcard/example.html">
```

if WebView loads remote file(http), it open in current iframe. otherwise it fails

// it opens in current iframe

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com">
```

**I want to work the same as when I used http**

does anyone has idea?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this link out :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748226/webview-iframe-overflow?rq=1

Comment: @KishuDroid I mean the src of the iframe. It is not the address of loadUrl.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: @KishuDroid I got it! That's only a bug!. loadUrl was called somewhere. Thanks for your attention.